# How to display an image from Asset Catalog in Today Extension?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, notificationcenter

I'm working on a Today Extension for iOS8. My App Group is set up correctly and I can successfully use NSUserDefaults to send simple bits of data to my extension (using [this tutorial](http://www.glimsoft.com/06/28/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial/)).

In the storyboard for my extension, I've placed an image onto the storyboard and set the image to be an asset I have in my Asset Catalog. Even though it appears in Interface Builder, when I run the app on a device and simulator the image doesn't display.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Make sure the asset catalog is included in the target for your Today extension.

Comment: Thank you. For anyone looking for this, select the .xcassets from the Navigator, then in the Utility menu (right side), you can set the Target Membership in the File Inspector tab.