# How to access image files in a today notification widget

Tags: xcode, swift, widget, ios8-today-widget

Is there any kind of restriction when accessing image through widgets extension?
I have an image within Widget extension Supporting Files group called pocket.png

I want to use this image through by Widget custom view controller and as usual i wrote this code

```
var pocketImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "pocket")
```

To my surprise this code returns blank. Tried with pocket.png same problem.

Now i tried to do with image with path and even the below code returns nil

```
let pathx = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pocket", ofType: "png")
```

So how do i access local available image?
Note: The same code works fine when i use it in the main application with its local image.

Comment: See my SO question on using Asset Catalog images in both the app and extension http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963059/how-to-dislay-an-image-from-asset-catalog-in-today-extension

Comment: You should use image in the same target only.Make sure you are not accessing the image from your main target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with xcode which didn't copy the images properly. I had to delete and copy them again to fix the issue.